# How to update LocalDateTime field with JPA?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I used to store `LocalDateTime` fields using an older JPA version (spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.5.9.RELEASE) which stored this timestamp in a `tinyblob#VARBINARY` field in my MySQL database.

Now I am upgrading to JPA 2.1.5, which does have support for Java Date API objects. So now it expects the field to be a `datetime#TIMESTAMP` field type.

How do I migrate these old blob fields, that contains data the way JPA used to store objects, to timestamp type and converting the values to valid timestamps as well?